# Prism Button click command

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

Im try to open Drawer menu (Syncfusion control) via Behaviors command

Xaml

```
<Button x:Name="hamburgerButton" 
                                HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" 
                                HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="20"
                                BackgroundColor="#1aa1d6" >
                            <Button.Behaviors>
                                <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Clicked" 
                                      Command="{Binding HamburgerButton}" />
                            </Button.Behaviors>
```

VM cs

```
    public DelegateCommand HamburgerButton { get; private set; }   
 public QuickPartViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{ 
    HamburgerButton = new DelegateCommand(HamburgerButton_Clicked);
}
    public void HamburgerButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {            
                navigationDrawer.ToggleDrawer();
            }
```

If HamburgerButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) with arguments  then i have error -// Argumment: cannot convert from 'method group' to Action

if I'm remove Argumments it does't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overthinking things. Just bind the command to the button.

in the page:

```
<Button Command="{Binding HamburgerCommand}" />
```

in the view model:

```
public QuickPartViewModel()
{ 
    HamburgerCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnHamburger);
}

public DelegateCommand HamburgerCommand { get; }   

private void OnHamburger()
{            
     navigationDrawer.ToggleDrawer();
}
```

Give [the docs](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/Getting-Started.html) a try...

Comment: not work unfortunately, 
if  I do not MVVM  
like code behind in xaml.cs 
private void HamburgerButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            navigationDrawer.ToggleDrawer();
        }
and use event in xaml "Clicked" then everything work great

Comment: You can, of course, listen to the `Clicked` event with an event handler in code behind, but if you put the `MVVM` tag on the question and talk about commands, one assumes you want to use a view model and bind to a command in there.